# Unable to Configure CAS Database Authentication

Tags: cas

Following [this tutorial](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/22/cas51-dbauthn-tutorial/) I am unable to configure database configuration.

Using the cas-overlay, I've added settings to the `cas.properties` file, but when I run the project it fails to authenticate.

I don't think the settings are loading completely, because my `cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.type=BCRYPT` setting doesn't take.

I'm coming to this pretty green, so I feel like there is a gap in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. It wasn't necessarily the cas.properties file was wrong. I was actually missing a dependency that imports JDBC support.

Their documentation kind of reads like it is supported, but makes an assumption the reader knows to add the dependency.

Added this to my overlay pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
</dependency>
```